# How to redirect StandardOutput in systemd to the screen

Tags: centos7, systemd

I'm trying to redirect the output of a script that is run by the ExecStartPre to the screen.

I know that I need to use the standardOutput in the service`s file, but the options didnt work when I tested them (journal+console,tty). 
I used journal+console and the output was saved only in the journal. I also tried tty but I didnt get output.

```
[Service]
Type=notify
StandartOutput=tty
ExecStartPre=somescript
ExecStartPre=someotherscript
ExecStart=somescript
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your spelling. It is StandardOutput, not StandartOutput.